# How do I translate this dynamic collection expression from VB.NET into C#?

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have this very succinct expression in vb.NET which makes it easy to test to see if a value is in a list of known string literals but I don't know how to translate it to C#. (It is made all the more difficult because I cannot search for it knowing exactly how to describe what the name of this type of expression is)

```
Dim test as String = "test"
If {"test", "test2"}.Contains(test) Then

End If
```

Comment: That is an array literal, in the same sense that you have `String` literals or `Integer` literals.

Comment: This isn't a dynamic collection expression. This is a simple `Enumerable.Contains(someValue)` on an array

Comment: You could clean up the code by defining the array in a separate line. If that method is called frequently, you can avoid allocating a new array every time the method is called by storing the array in a field

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use:

```cs
if (new [] {"test1, test2"}.Contains(test)) {
}
```

Comment: This seems to be one of the few examples where VB is more succinct than c#